# php difference between echo and a simple txt file

Tags: php, echo

I am very new to php language and I got a small question to ask. As last image shows, I save a .txt file named "test2" with "Hello, World!" written on it and a .php file named "test1" with code:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, World!"
?>
```

Now, what is the difference between them two? Besides the font after opening them, I see no difference. All I want is just display some text and nothing else, which one should I use? Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Only some text on a browser?

Comment: If you don't need scripting via a language, then don't use scripting.... simply echoing static text is pretty pointless

Comment: Why only text? Whats your final goal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences are minor, the PHP file will probably **add a HTTP header** to the response indicating PHP. Depends on configuration.

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.22
```

Depending on the Webserver, for example using **fcgi**, PHP will not be loaded during text file request, so it might be faster than PHP echo (at least it uses a few MB less of memory).

Using Apache without fcgi for example (when the PHP interpreter is loaded as a **module**), any requests will trigger to load PHP so there is barely a difference, **text file generates I/O** whereas PHP opcodes may be cached in memory (on a second or third request).

Another difference is, the webserver recognizes the **mime-type** of the text file, but for PHP there is a default mime-type in the **php.ini**. That mean's your `echo`-PHP-script will probably render as HTML instead of `text/plain`.